# Get image from localhost to localhost with express and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, express, http

I´m building an app with NodeJs and Angular

The server runs on http://localhost:9000

And the app runs on http://localhost:4200

I have an endpoint whose looks like this http://localhost:9000/users
I use this to retrive all users

The set returned has a key like this `{ photo: myphoto.jpg }`

When I loop the set of data, I want to render the image as this way

```
  <img src="{{ url }}/uploads/users/{{ user.photo }}" alt="{{ user.name }} {{ user.last_name }}"
    class="img-fluid shadow-sm avatar100 ml-auto mr-auto d-block rounded-circle">
```

Where `url` is http://localhost:9000 and user.photo is `myphoto.jpg`

The complete route is `http://localhost:9000/uploads/users/myfoto.jpg`
There is the photo hosted, but the server is throwing an error

> Cannot GET /uploads/users/myfoto.jpg

I think, the server is interpreting the URL as API route, and obviously is not declared on routes file.

I want to only retrive the image, how could I do that?

I don´t know what part of my code I can show here. Routes? Front-end? Project structure? Tell me what do you need

Comment: You can not serve any files directly to do that either you have to define the route or serve it as static files.
you should check express static files serve.
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Kabooom! @ShivamMishra thank you sensei, if you can set it as answer I vote up it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Express, you have to create a route that will handle your image URLs.  By default, Express (or the built-in node.js web server) does not serve ANY files.  So, it will only serve a file if you create a handler for that specific URL and program that handler to deliver the desired file.

If your images are directly in the file system where the URL base filename matches the actual filename in your server file system, you could use `express.static()` to create a single route that would serve all your images.

For example, you could use express.static like this:

```
 app.use("/uploads/users", express.static("/uploads/users"));
```

This would allow a URL requested from:

```
http://localhost:9000/uploads/users/myphoto.jpg
```

to be automatically served from the server-side file system at

```
/uploads/users/myphoto.jpg
```

It would similarly work for any other matching name in that same directory (or even sub-directories of that directory if the sub-directory was also in the URL).

In general, you don't want to surface internal path names such as `/uploads/users` all the way back to the user's HTML pages.  So, you could do this instead in the HTML page:

```
<img src="/images/myphoto.jpg">
```

And, this on the server:

```
 app.use("/images", express.static("/uploads/users"));
```

This will take any http requests that start with a path of `/images` and look for the matching filename in `/uploads/users` on the server, thus not exposing the internals of your server directory structure to the client.  It creates the notion of an abstract `/images` URL that your server can then process and get the images from wherever they happen to be stored on the server.

Answer (score 0):

$ npm i multer

and server add

app.use("/public", express.static("public")); //The folder where the file is located